# Tool to extract Documents on basis of list of IDs

Tags: data-export, document

Does anyone know of a tool that if I have a list of Document IDs (from Document Object) I can download the files attached to them? Dataloader seems to just want to give me a body string of Bytes, not the actual file.

File Exporter is having issues as per recent updates. Additionally, dataloader.io only gave us the base64 encoded for documents.

Comment: Looking for some alternate options. I am familiar with the answers that were posted on that question.